# font-family defined on body is not inherited by the input tag and placeholder

Tags: css, fonts, css-cascade

How can I inherit the font style from `body` to the `input` text and placeholder?

```css
body {
  font-family: "Circular", -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, "Segoe UI",
    "Roboto", "Oxygen", "Ubuntu", "Cantarell", "Fira Sans", "Droid Sans",
    "Helvetica Neue", sans-serif;
}
```

the `input` tag is being used:

```css
<input
   type="text"
   value={value}
   onChange={onChange}
   placeholder={placeholder}
   className={styles.input}
/>
```

Currently, the global `body` `font-family` styling is not applying to the `input` text and placeholder. It only works if I add the font style explicitly like this:

```
.input {
    font-family: "Circular", -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, "Segoe UI",
    "Roboto", "Oxygen", "Ubuntu", "Cantarell", "Fira Sans", "Droid Sans",
    "Helvetica Neue", sans-serif;

  &::placeholder {
    font-family: "Circular", -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, "Segoe UI",
    "Roboto", "Oxygen", "Ubuntu", "Cantarell", "Fira Sans", "Droid Sans",
    "Helvetica Neue", sans-serif;
  }
}
```

Comment: add font-family in placeholder too

Comment: `color: $extended-grey-1;` is not declaration of font-family. Try `font-family: inherit;`

Comment: @Justinas It works, thanks! Is it required for every input tag?